# Shared Dictionary in VB.net service crashes service when instantiated

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, windows-services, vb.net-2010, shared

I am newer to VB.net and I trying to create a vb.net service that watches a directory and records the paths of files placed in the directory for further processing.

To do this I have a public shared dictionary inside the main class.

```
Public Class Service
    Private Shared pdfqueue As Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

If I try to run any member functions such as `pdfqueue.Count` I get a null reference exception.

As a response I tried changing this to:

```
Private Shared pdfqueue As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

I rebuilt the project and started the service and the service stopped immediately, logging to the System Service Control Manager that the service terminated unexpectedly.

I followed this up by instantiating the variable inside a Try Catch block inside a function hoping I could capture an exception, but nothing was logged:

```
    Try
        PDFtoTiff.pdfqueue = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Catch ex As Exception
        EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

I am able to create a shared Boolean variable and set it to True on the very next line, but it seems anything I do with the dictionary crashes the service.

I'm rather confused by this and would appreciate any help.

Comment: try `Private Shared pdfqueue As NEW Dictionary(Of String, String)` I am curious why this is Shared.

Comment: You're barking up the wrong tree.  It certainly was wrong to use it before it was set to a new object, but once you fixed that, it should have been fine.  If it's still failing, it's for some other reason.  There's nothing inherently wrong about shared dictionaries in services.

Comment: That sounds like good advice. I will try stripping down the other functions in the process to see if I can isolate that other reason.

Comment: @StevenDoggart, you were exactly right. The error is in another function, but only got exposed when I fixed the earlier error. Thank you for your help.